# Azure Web Apps : Is it possible to have instance with more than 4 cores and 7 GB RAM?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to scale up service plan for web apps. I can see 2 tiers i.e. standard and premium.

However for both tiers, I noticed there isn't anything that has more than 7 GB RAM and 4 CORES.

Am I missing anything?

Horizontal scaling is not the option for us due to how web sites manages the shared files (code/indexing) etc.

Comment: What are you referring to, regarding issues with shared files?

Comment: Isssue is that lucene index files gets *.write lock when more than one instances tries to update indexes. Works ok with web roles

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [App Service Environments](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-app-service-environment/). When you use an ASE, you have a new **P4 Premium tier** available.

If you check the [Pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/), you'll see a P4 Premium for 8 Cores and 14Gb of RAM.

Here is how to create an [App Service Environment](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-how-to-create-an-app-service-environment/). And a [more technical detailed intro](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-app-service-environment-intro/).

[image: P4 Premium]

Comment: Thanks. Does App Service Environment contains web apps? What exactly do I need to do to enable this.

Comment: The ASE is just like an App Service but of a "Premium" level, you can put your Web Apps in it. Normal App Services are running on shared hardware (you still have dedicated resources). ASEs run on dedicated hardware (it's a bit more complex but so you get the idea).It's best described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-app-service-environment-intro/). And here is [how to create an ASE](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-how-to-create-an-app-service-environment/).